# R push to dataframe

Tags: r

I want to push vectors of different lengths into an empty dataframe.
How can I do this?
I've tried:

```
df<-NULL

final_data <- rbind(df, c(1,2) )
final_data <- rbind(df, c(1,2,3) )
final_data <- rbind(df, c(1,2,3,4) )
```

But it returns type of double

```
1|2|3|4
```

I need to get

```
1|2
1|2|3
1|2|3|4
```

Comment: If you have a vector of different lengths, it may be better to store it in a `list`.  `lst <- list(1:2, 1:3, 1:4)`  But it can be converted to data.frame.  `as.data.frame(do.call(rbind, lapply(lst, 'length<-', max(lengths(lst)))))`

Comment: it's show me error  "could not find function "lengths"

Comment: I think it was introduced in R 3.2.1 or so.  Which version of R you have?

Comment: @akrun is correct. If you would like a data frame with different row lengths, what you want is a list of lists. Is it acceptable to use NA when the lengths are not the same?

Comment: Also, you need to use `rbind(final_data,c("whatever")` rather than repeatedly `rbind`ing on `df`.

Answer (score 0):

probably not the most elegant way of doing it, but this works:

```
df <- data.frame()

df <- rbind( df, t(data.frame(c(1,2)) ))
df

x = c(1,2,3)
#add column of NAs to match length of new column
df <- cbind(df,data.frame(rep(NA,length(x) -ncol(df))))
names(df) <- paste('V',seq(1,ncol(df)),sep='')
df <- rbind( df, t(data.frame(x) ))
df

x = c(1,2,3,4)
df <- cbind(df,data.frame(rep(NA,length(x) -ncol(df))))
names(df) <- paste('V',seq(1,ncol(df)),sep='')
df <- rbind( df, t(data.frame(x) ))
df
```